# Prove $f$ is constant with conditions about derivatives.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

Let $B_1(0)$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n,f\in C^2(B_1(0))$,Prove that

(1)If $\sum_{i,j}x_ix_j\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}=0$,$\nabla f(0)=0$,
then $f$ is constant.

(2)If f satisfies $x_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}-x_j \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=0,1\leq i,j\leq n$,then $f$ is constant on the sphere $\{|x|=\frac{1}{2}\}$.

$f$ can not attain its maximum or minimum in $B_1(0)$ because of the elliptic condition $\sum_{i,j}x_ix_j\geq 0$.The condition also reminds me of Taylor formula,but it doesn't work.For (2),I may use Green's formulas if it involves $x_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\cdots$

Comment: *Hint*: Think in polar coordinates.

Comment: Could you add some details?The equation may be very complicated...

Comment: Note that $x^i\frac\partial{\partial x^i}=r\frac\partial{\partial r}$ for (1), for (2) it is analogous to 2D $x\frac\partial{\partial y}-y\frac\partial{\partial x}=\frac\partial{\partial\theta}$.